# Bot is not sending messages in the server through on_ready fucntion [python]

Tags: json, python-3.x, discord

First, I mentioned the code below:

[main.py]

```
#MODULES
import os
import json
import asyncio
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands

#CUSTOM MODULES
from Features.log import ErrrorLogs

#LOADING CUSTOM MODULES
ErrrorLogs()

#LOADING CONFIG FILE FROM CONFIG FOLDER
def load_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        return json.load(file)
    
Config_Path = r'Config\config.json'

data = load_data(Config_Path)

#LOADING ENVIRONEMENT FILE
env_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Config', '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path = env_path)

#GETTING VARIABLES FROM CONFIG FOLDER
Token = os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN')

Bot_Channel = data['BOT_CHANNEL'] # Bot response channel id.
Welcome_Channel = data['WELCOME_CHANNEL'] # Welcome channel id.

Prefix = data['PREFIX'] # Bot prefix.

#DEFINING INTENTS
intents = discord.Intents.all()

#BOT PREFIX
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = Prefix, intents = intents)

#MAIN

#(1) Bot Goes Online Message.
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('|' + '-'*50 + '>')
    print(f' {client.user.name} has envaded the server...')
    print(' Bot Name:', client.user.name)
    print(' Bot ID:', client.user.id)
    print('|' + '-'*50 + '>')

    channel = client.get_channel(Bot_Channel)

    await channel.send('Example test')

#(2) Loading Cogs Folder.
async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir('./Cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await client.load_extension(f'Cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

#(3) Loading All The Fucntions.
async def main():
    await load()
    await client.start(Token)

#RUNNING THE BOT
asyncio.run(main())
```

I have issue in this part

```
#(1) Bot Goes Online Message.
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('|' + '-'*50 + '>')
    print(f' {client.user.name} has envaded the server...')
    print(' Bot Name:', client.user.name)
    print(' Bot ID:', client.user.id)
    print('|' + '-'*50 + '>')

    channel = client.get_channel(Bot_Channel)

    await channel.send('Example text')
```

Bot is printing the message in the terminal, but now sending the message in the discord channel, don't know why. It is not even giving any error.

I tried to send a message from a different file[`test.py`] like this one:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json

intents = discord.Intents.all()

def load_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        return json.load(file)
    
Config_Path = r'Config\config.json'

data = load_data(Config_Path)

Bot_Channel = data['BOT_CHANNEL']
Welcome_Channel = data['WELCOME_CHANNEL']
Prefix = data['PREFIX']

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= 'PREFIX', intents = intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is online)
    print('Bot_Channel: ' + Bot_Channel)
    print('Prefix: ' + Prefix)
    print('Welcome_Channel: ' + Welcome_Channel)

    channel = bot.get_channel(Bot_Channel)

    if channel:
        await channel.send("Hello, I'm ready!")
    else:
        print("Channel not found.")

bot.run('123456789')
```

Also this my channel.json file

```
{
    "PREFIX": "!",
    "BOT_CHANNEL": "11967.......",
    "WELCOME_CHANNEL": "1196........"
}
```

This code is printing everything except sending the messsage in the server channel.

Now I am confused. I appreciate the help on this topic.

I tried to explore the related question on this site, but nothing seems to work for me.

And pls tell the solution based on very first code I mentioned since I am originally using `asyncio.run(main())`. [I thought using `asyncio.run(main()`) needed some changes before sending messages]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main.py file I can see multiple issues like the loading of cogs can done easily just by putting the code outside the function as there is no need of for function here. And also to run the bot you should use `client.run` instead of `client.start`.

After making changes the code should look like:

```py
for filename in os.listdir('./Cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await client.load_extension(f'Cogs.{filename[:-3]}')


client.run(Token)
```

I think the issue here is with `client.get_channel` as the get_channel relies on the cache and since you want to get channel in the starting you will have to use `client.fetch_channel`.

The code should look like:

```py
#(1) Bot Goes Online Message.
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('|' + '-'*50 + '>')
    print(f' {client.user.name} has envaded the server...')
    print(' Bot Name:', client.user.name)
    print(' Bot ID:', client.user.id)
    print('|' + '-'*50 + '>')

    channel = await client.fetch_channel(Bot_Channel)

    await channel.send('Example text')
```

Comment: Thanks buddy the code is working now. And also thanks for fixing the issue related to cogs.